# Is there any PDF creator and viewer/renderer library in FLUTTER with features like zoom-in, zoom-out, page-separator, gesture-recognizer?

Tags: flutter, pdf-generation, zooming, uigesturerecognizer, pinchzoom

PDF generator and renderer library needed in FLUTTER with features like:

1. zoom-in,
2. zoom-out,
3. page-separator,
4. gesture-recognizer,
5. double-tap to zoom?

**If there is no such library what things are required to create such library using flutter ?**

Comment: Did you take a look at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_pdf_renderer ?

Comment: @MazinIbrahim This will help for viewing the pdf. Is there any PDF GENERATOR package or library?

Comment: Yes, there are many PDF packages in the dart's packages website https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=pdf , search in them but probably you won't find one with all the features you need.

Comment: Does pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_pdf_renderer work for iOS? @MazinIbrahim Not working in my case.

Comment: I didn't try it, But the author usually declare when a plugin or a certain in it isn't compatible with a certain platform.

Answer (score 1):

flutter's native_pdf_view has all the features you mentioned.
https://pub.dev/packages/native_pdf_view